# How to change tab key selection color with css?

Tags: css

When I press tab key and select a button it gets a border. Is it possible to change its color or remove the border completely with css?

Comment: You can do `outline: none` and it will fix it but I'd urge you to keep it as-is (unless you have some other visible distinction) because there may be users who aren't using the mouse and this outline will let them know which item is focussed. Have a look at this - http://outlinenone.com/

Comment: Yes, you can override `:focus` and `:active` styles in css.

Comment: thanks, `outline:none` worked correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
input:focus {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click inside the text fields to see a yellow background:</p>

<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>

<p><b>Note:</b> For :focus to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: code-only answers are discouraged.